# AfterViewInit is called too early?

Tags: jquery, angular, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular5

I am developing an angular website with `Angular 5.2.1`. I created a component I use multiple times in one view. To access it create a unique Id for the component in the constructor of this component.

In the `AfterViewInit` event I want to subscribe to an event. But it seems the component is still not available a short time after `AfterViewInit` was fired.

**HTML**

```
<a data-toggle="collapse" href="#{{componentId}}">Toggle</a>

<div id="{{componentId}}" class="collapse">
    <!-- tabset content -->
</div>
```

**Component**

```
declare var $: any

@Component({
    selector: 'my-component',
    templateUrl: './my-component.component.html'
})

export class MyComponentComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
    // Some inputs

    public componentId: string
    // Some other component variables

    constructor(
        private generatorService: GeneratorService
    ) {
        // Generate unique Id for the component, length 10
        this.componentId = this.generatorService.generateId(10)
    }

    ngOnInit() {
    }

    ngAfterViewInit(): void {
        console.log(this.componentId) // Correct id is printed to console
        console.log($('#' + this.componentId)) // Returning empty result

        // So this is not working:
        $('#' + this.componentId).on('hide.bs.collapse', () => {
            // Do something
        })
    }

    // Some other code
}
```

As far as I know, `AfterViewInit` normally is fired when the component has been completely initialized and added to DOM. When I wait a little moment and write `$('#[myComponentId]')` manually to console I get the correct result.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I just found a dirty workaround.

I wrote a recursive method which is called initially in the AfterViewInit method.

My component now looks like the following

```
declare var $: any

@Component({
    selector: 'my-component',
    templateUrl: './my-component.component.html'
})

export class MyComponentComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
    // Some inputs

    public componentId: string
    // Some other component variables

    private iteration: number = 0

    constructor(
        private generatorService: GeneratorService
    ) {
        // Generate unique Id for the component, length 10
        this.componentId = this.generatorService.generateId(10)
    }

    ngOnInit() {
    }

    ngAfterViewInit(): void {
        console.log(this.componentId) // Correct id is printed to console

        this.registerEvents()
    }

    registerEvents() {
        setTimeout(() => {
            if (!('#' + this.componentId)[0]) {
                this.iteration++
                this.registerEvents()
                return
            }

            console.log(this.iteration) // Prints a value between 3 and 5
            $('#' + this.componentId).on('hide.bs.collapse', () => {
                // Do something
            })
        }, this.iteration * 10)
    }

    // Some other code
}
```

I don't know why this is happening, but now I can work again.